# Selenium javascript error

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

selenium some time gives below error.but in some instance the same code pass through.should i catch exception and bypass? what could be the solution to passthrough

```
      [31morg.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: waiting for doc.body failed
  Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:646)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
```

java code is

```
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                    "return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
    wait.until(pageLoad);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to wait until page loads you can use following code

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeSpan.fromSeconds(30));
wait.until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
```

Comment: the solution you have provided is .net which is equivalent code above in java

Comment: your code seems right. can you extend the time and see if you still get the error?